# full screen website with small scroll enabled with delay/aimate

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a fullscreen website (100% height and width) with bootstrap and its jumbotron feature. Also added 10px border with body padding

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="jumbotron indx-BG" >
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body { padding: 10px; }

.indx-BG {
 background: url('...') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
 width: 100%;
}
```

works the way I want it. However I want to add a footer (unknown height) that cannot be seen unless the user scrolls down. I want to sight to remain responsive and fullscreen unless the user chooses to scroll, then the small extra footer will show.

EDIT - I want there to be a bit of a delay/animation to the scroll, similar to those sliders that 'push' content up/down

Comment: use 100vh for the height of the first div.

Comment: I forgot to add an edit which may make it not so simple

Comment: can you show us a working fiddle ?

Comment: I would if I knew how, and it is hard to find an example. closest thing I can find is on hugeinc.com when you scroll and the page switches from the large slider of h's to the grid is has the effect I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this one helps. i added 2 other section so you can see the animation. The code detects the scroll wether it is from bottom to top or top to bottom. if it detects scroll up, it will re initialize the scroll animation and when it detects scroll down, it will animate the scroll going to the footer.

```js
var domouse = true;
var content_down = $('footer').offset().top;
var content_up = $('div').offset().top;
$('body').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {

  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
    if (!domouse)
    return;
    domouse = false;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: content_up
    }, 1000, function(){
      domouse = true;
    });
  } else {
    if (!domouse)
    return;
    domouse = false;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: content_down
    }, 1000, function(){
      domouse = true;
    });
  }

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
}
footer {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  main section
</div>
<footer>
  this is a footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. The animations for me don't seem to work properly and the code seems to make the scrolling jagged. However I think you may have made it more difficult than I expected. I just want to the footer to have a bit of delay when it scrolls up. Only one full-screen section and the footer

Comment: ahh much better thank you! two things. 1. can/do I put that code in my header with script tags and 2. can I increase delay when it scrolls up much the same as you have it when it scrolls down (which factor controls that part?)

Comment: Yes. Just increase the timing function of animate function to make the scroll slower. i putted 500 mili second, you can do 1000 for 1second. just dont forget to add 100vh for the main section.

Answer (score -1):

Try to window height this is the best way:

```
//#main-slider
var WindowHeight = $(window).height();
$('#demo').css('height',WindowHeight);

$(window).resize(function(){'use strict',
    $('#demo').css('height',WindowHeight);
});
```